# Adding space in cells

Tags: c#, excel

I have 2 columns (entire col H and I)of an excel which contain start time and end time as

```
STARTTIME  ENDTIME
2pm        4pm
12pm       3am
```

I want to add a space between time and pm/am(i.e., 2pm will change to 2 pm)
I am using `Microsoft.Office.interop.Excel` and have specified the range.
Now, how do I add a space?

Answer (score 1):

```
string cellValue = "12pm";
cellValue = cellValue.Replace("pm"," pm");
cellValue = cellValue.Replace("am"," am");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the value of each cell by locating 'pm' or 'am' and insert a space character before it. Example:

```
string cellValue = "12pm";    
int index = cellValue.Pos("pm");
cellValue = cellValue.SubString(0, index) + " " + cellValue.SubString(index);
```

Comment: better would be to use Replace("pm", " pm") - that way wouldn't result in an exception if the string didn't contain "pm".